# Android UI thread and message handler confusion

Tags: android

The code that follows comes from p.58-61 of the book "Android Developer's Cookbook".  The book introduces the code in the context of messages being a way to pass information between threads.  It describes the code by saying: "The timer is run in a background thread so it does not block the UI thread, but it needs to update the UI whenever the time changes."

I'm confused because I don't see two threads.  To me it seems that the main UI thread posts a runnable message to its own message queue (and that message then re-posts itself with a time-delay).  Am I missing something?

```
package com.cookbook.background_timer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BackgroundTimer extends Activity {
    //keep track of button presses, a main thread task
    private int buttonPress=0;
    TextView mButtonLabel;

    //counter of time since app started, a background task
    private long mStartTime = 0L;
    private TextView mTimeLabel;

    //Handler to handle the message to the timer task
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        if (mStartTime == 0L) {
            mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
        }

        mTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mButtonLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trigger);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){
                mButtonLabel.setText("Pressed " + ++buttonPress + " times");
            }
        });        
    }

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final long start = mStartTime;
            long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds     = seconds % 60;

            mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d",seconds));
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second thread is kind of hidden. It's when you call `postDelayed(mUpdateTImeTask,100)` in `onCreate()`. The handler has a thread in it that counts down the delay time (100 milliseconds in this case) and then runs mUpdateTImeTask. Note that at the end of the `run()` method of mUpdateTimeTask, it puts itself back in the handler's timer thread by calling `postDelayed()` again.

The Android api has lots of classes like Handler and AsyncTask that make it easier to do multithreading. These classes hide a lot of the nuts and bolts of threading (which is what makes them nice to use). Unfortunately, that makes it hard to learn what's going on--you sort of have to know what's going on in order to learn it. :)

Comment: So you're saying that a Handler has an invisible thread (distinct from the thread that the Handler delivers messages to), and the invisible thread's job is to post delayed messages to the handler queue when the delay time expires. The main/non-invisible thread still executes the actual messages. Correct?

Comment: I think that's right. The handler actually hands the job off to the Looper for your application. That's the object that runs the entire event loop; it also sets up the thread used to time the delivery of messages to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `Runnable` class is essentially a class used in threading. The `run()` method will be invoked by the interface that calls it (the `Handler`) and - in this implementation - the application sets up the `Handler` to run `mUpdateTimeTask` 100ms after that line is executed. Which will then run everything in the `run()` method in your `Runnable`.

When `onCreate()` is called, your application gets the `mTimeLabel` object from the view and it is updated with the `setText()` method in your `Runnable`. That will update the time on your UI thread and then register itself to go off in another 200 milliseconds.

Comment: As I understand it... Android's main UI thread instantiates the BackgroundTimer activity, which includes a Handler.  A Handler delivers messages to the thread that created it, which is the main UI thread in this case.  While executing the BackgroundTimer's onCreate method, the main UI thread posts a message to its own handler.  Following the execution of onCreate, the main UI thread processes events/messages, e.g. the runnable message that it posted earlier.  So the main UI thread ends up executing the Runnable code, not some other thread.

Comment: Ah, yes. I should have read the API documentation a bit more. I think when they say "two threads", I think they are basically saying that the code being run in the Runnable is not going to block the main UI thread so you can still interact with the UI and not receive an ANR message while the Handler is waiting to execute the Runnable again.

Comment: I have revised my answer a little bit, I was originally thinking of the class AsyncTask compared to Runnable. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no second thread here! You can test easily by putting some expensive code in the runnable, which will block the UI thread. You have to make a `new Thread(Runnable)` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you need almost in every project. I had to add a Timer class in my open-source Aniqroid library which is get triggered in the UI thread and utilizes the Handler.postDelayed() feature without having to write all the boiler-plate code.

http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/ (Look for downloads at the bottom or use google code project to see more download options: http://code.google.com/p/aniqroid/downloads/list)

The class documentation is here: http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/com/sileria/android/Timer.html